# Connecting to private TCP service on Azure VM

Tags: azure, tcp

I am testing my own TCP client/server software, trying to use an Azure VM for testing.  I have done this successfully on a Azure VM that I set up over a year ago.  Now I have created a new VM that I need to test with.  My service is installed on the VM and is monitoring port 18971.  In the Azure portal, I have created an "endpoint" for TCP for that port.  The machine is running Windows 2012.  I have configured Windows Firewall with inbound and outbound rules to allow all TCP traffic to/from that port.  I have also tried turning the firewall off.  Still, my client software does not work, I receive error 10060 on the Winsock API "connect". I tried both the domain name and the IP address.

Any ideas of what else I have to do to allow TCP traffic? I am pretty sure this is an Azure configuration problem - I have successfully tested the software on direct connected machines as well as the old Azure VM I mentioned (I see no difference between it and the one I am trying now).

Comment: If you are using VM - can you connect from the same box to itself via localhost?  Can you connect to yourself via the "public ip" even though you are on the same VM?

Comment: Is something else running on that port? Have you tried changing port of your application?

Comment: do `netstat` command to find out if there are other services running on port. Is the old working VM also Server 2012?

Comment: Yes I can connect to my service at 127.0.0.1.  When I do netstat -a I can see something is monitoring TCP on local address 0.0.0.0:18971.  Presumably mine, since if I shut down my service, it goes away.  It is just when I try to access the service from outside that I cannot connect. Some issue with firewall or Azure security, I just don't know what.

Comment: Can you allow the port 18971 in your NSG associated with your Azure VM or subnet?

Comment: @JeffMcKay, May I know any update on your side?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you.  I was able to get it working by re-creating the endpoint, this time disabling the "floating IP address" feature.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JeffMcKay  It would be better you can post your solution as an answer to close this case instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use the new type of VM with a resource manager on the old portal which you have "endpoint" for TCP for that port. You have to open some ports (endpoints) on new VM via the new portal. Refer to [this](http://michaelsync.net/2015/09/28/where-is-the-endpoint-setting-for-vm-in-new-azure-portal).

For the new type of VM with a resource manager, you have to allow the port 18971 in the inbound port rules of NSG associated with your Azure VM or subnet.

Navigate to your virtual machine settings, and find Networking---Add inbound port rule.

[image]